# C++ writing to text file corrupted

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I have this code that encrypts data according to this [pdf].[1](https://github.com/jorsutton92/IncorrectOutput)
The problem that I'm having is that the code produces the correct output. when i "cat" the outputfile I get the correct answer, however if i open the file in the text editor i get results that look like this:

```
0068 6e74 7264 727a 0073 7558 6569 7965
0061 6779 686f 6570 0064 6d62 6465 6358
0074 7265 6568 6168 0075 7058 5862 7469
0065 6e72 6d65 676c 0073 6377 6864 6e6f
0073 6d6e 7479 7465 006c 6775 5869 6561
```

The expected output is:

```
 hntrdrzsuXeiyeagyhoepdmbdecXtreehahupXXbtienrmeglscwhdnosmntytelguXiea
```

using this string as the original argument and the Keys: CORNFLAKES and BLACKHORSE

```
sendresupplytothebridgebythechurchXXammoneededurgentlywithmagazinesXXX
```

is this a memory issue, is my stream failing? I feel like I'm overlooking something I just can't see what.

this is how it encrypts:

```
string encrypt(string &key, string &toEncrypt)
{
    int height= 1;
    string result = "";

    vector<vector<char> > matrix(key.length(), vector<char>(2));

    string::iterator it=toEncrypt.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        matrix[i][0] = key.at(i);
    }


    // put info into matrix
    printf("%s\n", key.c_str());
    while( it!=toEncrypt.end()) // while string still has more chars
    {
        //printf("newline----\n");
        for (int col = 0; col < key.length(); col++,it++)
        {
            if (it != toEncrypt.end())
            {
                if(*it == '\0'){it++;}
                matrix[col].push_back(*it);
                printf("%c", *it);
                continue;
            }
                if(col < key.length())  
                    matrix[col].push_back('X');
                printf("%c", 'X');

        }
        height++;
        printf("\n");
    }
    //parse trough the matrix
    printf("\n");
    BubbleSort(matrix);
    printf("\n");

    printf("PAST BUBBLE SORT\n");
    for (int c = 0; c < key.length(); c++)
    {
        for (int r= 1; r < matrix[0].size(); r++)
        {
            result += matrix[c][r];
            printf("%c",matrix[c][r]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    printf("THE RESULT IS%s\n", result.c_str());
    return result;
}
```

This is how I am writing to a file:

```
string file = "\0";
printf("Please Enter the name of the file that contains the text to be encrypted with the extention.\n");
getline(cin, file, '\n');

string line;
string encrypted;

transposition_encr encryptor = transposition_encr(k1,k2);

ifstream myfile (file.c_str());
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
         encrypted += line; 
    }

    myfile.close();

}
else 
{
    cout << "Unable to open file\n";
    return -1; 
}

cout << encrypted << endl;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout<< encrypted << endl;
encrypted = encryptor.encryption(line);
cout<< encrypted << endl;

string str = "outputfile-encrypted-str.txt";
ofstream myfile2(str.c_str());
  if (myfile2.is_open())
  {
   myfile2 << encrypted;
   myfile2.close();
  }
   // else cout << "Unable to open file\n";
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/jorsutton92/IncorrectOutput) to the code

Comment: How do you expect the output to be?

Comment: the output should be this using the keys: CORNFLAKES and BLACKHORSE hntrdrzsuXeiyeagyhoepdmbdecXtreehahupXXbtienrmeglscwhdnosmntytelguXiea its the same as in the pdf.

Comment: i should mention that the encrypt method gets called twice and passes the results from one string into the next call

Comment: can you add the expected output to your question, with appropriate line breaks?

Comment: It sounds as if the problem is with your text editor. Which one are you using, and do you have the same problem if you try a different one?

Comment: i edited the post with the arguments and the expected output

Comment: I used gedit and it outputed it in chinese-like characters, then i used sublime and got the hex values post above in the question. I also have ran in on a Macbook pro and a computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: But when you use `cat` you get "hntrdr..." Fascinating. If you give us enough code to reproduce the error, I'll certainly take a look.

Comment: i will tar up all the files (Makefile included) and give a link in one second. I apreciate it. I just want to know what's causing it!

Comment: i edited the code the link is now at the bottom, here it is [again](https://github.com/jorsutton92/IncorrectOutput)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with

```
vector<char>(2)
```

as default elements in `matrix` and then `push_back()` to those. In the end, you discard the first one with

```
for (int r= 1; r < matrix[0].size(); r++)
```

but that still leaves you with a null byte. You probably want to start with an empty vector and use all of its elements.

Comment: so i need a 2 Dimensional vector and the first row is for the Keyword, then I start pushing back to the next row in the other vector. that for loop is just used to grab the elements of the vector and put them into a string as a check to make sure the content is correct. Interesting enough, when i change to an empty vector i get a segfault:11.

Comment: @jcjunction: This answer is correct. The null bytes are propagating into the output file, where they confuse text editors. I can't parse your comment, but you are being careless with these vectors.

Comment: i guess i have my code mixed up then. what does this mean then: vector<vector<char> > matrix(key.length(), vector<char>(2));

Comment: It creates an (outer) vector and passes a size and another (inner) vector to the constructor. The first argument is the number of elements, the second is their value. Try to locate that info (it concerns a standard type, after all!) in the web. Finding it is an important skill that you will need again in the future.